# Add Folder to Finder Favorites using Terminal

Tags: finder, macos, customization, high-sierra

I'm not sure whether this is actually possible or not but I'm trying to add a newly created folder into the **favorites** section of the Finder window.

If it is possible how can I achieve this? I have googled for this but couldn't find anything concrete. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The information about what appears in the Favorites section of the finder windows is kept in the configuration file:

/home/<your_user_name_here>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist

there is an explanation of the file's contents here:
https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/finder-sidebar-preferences-location/

and macOS includes a tool to manipulate the plists from terminal:
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy

You can find an introduction to the tool here:
http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2015/06/27/a-simple-plistbuddy-tutorial/

and a sample discussion about using it here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/macenterprise/Ks-zHlY3h5I

However, if you don't want to figure out everything by yourself you can use an utility published on github that manages the sidebar contents from the terminal line:

https://github.com/mosen/mysides

OTH

Comment: Unfortunately it seems the file `com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` is no longer present in MacOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a binary file at 
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Could you please explain how this helps in solving the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the parent of your newly created folder (cd ..) and run `open .` 
Your newly created folder should appear in Finder. Select it, press **File -> Add to sidebar**. Your folder is now present on the Favourites column

Comment: How does this qualify as a Terminal-based solution?

Comment: This was a real straightforward solution that took me less than a minute. Less of a hassle than installing anything or using a guide.

Comment: Yeah but you can't automate it in a dotfile, which is a major reason command line users want a plaintext solution

Comment: Does not work for files that cannot be viewed in the Finder, such as ~/.Trash, which remains hidden in the Finder even when Finder is displaying hidden files.